# C++: Why am I getting an error: "array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal"?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, casting

just started with C++. Was playing around with arrays and strings and encountered the error: "array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal". Here is my code:

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;

bool feast(string beast, string dish){
    int dishLn = dish.length();
    bool elig;
    char beastM[] = beast;
    char dishM[] = dish;

    elig = (beastM[0] == dishM[dishLn - 1]) ? true : false;

    return elig;
}
```

What I want to do is check if the first *char* of the *beast string* is equal to the last *char* of the *dish string* then output *true*, else *false*. So I am converting the *beast string* to an array of *chars* and then checking for their first element, for both *beast* and *dish*.

But I keep encountering this error.

Error corresponds to *char beastM[ ]* and *char dishM[ ]*. To my knowledge, this code should work since both *beast* and *dish* are given as strings in the function parameters. And converting them to a char array shouldn't be much of a problem.

All help is appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Not working. A new error came up: 'cannot initialize a variable of type 'char' with an rvalue of type 'const value_type *' (aka 'const char *')'

Comment: You declare two `char` arrays of unspecified size called `beastM` and `dishM` and attempt to initialize each of them using an object of type `std::string`. What exactly do you expect to happen there? What for exactly do you think you need `beastM` and `dishM`? Why not simply access the strings `beast` and `dish` directly!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can not directly assign a string to char array

```
bool feast(string beast, string dish){

    bool elig;

    elig = (beast.at(0) == dish.at(dish.length() - 1) ? true : false;

    return elig;
}
```